# Should i avoid using invoke?

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

Many times inside my code i am using an async task. When i want to change something inside ui thread then i am using code as described it below. I have already tried and tested this code.

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
         //Do sruff      
    }));
}
```

Is it good practise using invoke? Should i avoid it?

Comment: Can you define "good practice"? What code style are you comparing this to? Have you evaluated that other code style for its benefits and downsides?

Comment: How is *an async task* represented here, in practice? If you run a Task, so you execute code in a ThreadPool Thread, you need to marshal the results back to the UI Thread if you need to interact with UI elements. There's the [IProgress<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) interface for that. Or you can use the SynchronizationContext more directly. You can also Invoke(), keeping in mind that it's synchronous, *good* or *bad* depends on the context. -- If you use the async/await pattern, there's no need to marshal to the UI Thread. -- You should define your method.

Comment: Thank you Jim i will modify my question for make it clear.